# jqplot using rails not rendering pie chart

Tags: jqplot

I am trying to create a pie chart in jqplot. I am not sure if i am missing anything here but the chart is not rendering at all.

Below is one of my action method in dashboard_controller in Rails:

```
def index
    @trans = Transaction.joins(:category).group("categories.name").sum(:amount)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @trans }
    end
 end
```

here is the json data i got after executing the action method.

```
{"Bills & Utilities":1019.11,"Uncategorized":196.57,"Home":30.29,"Entertainment":300.0,"Food & Dining":465.45,"Personal Care":63.92,"Auto & Transport":571.44}
```

Here is my html and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jqplot/jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.ciParser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.json2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/jqplot/jqplot.css" />

<div id="chart10" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; width:460px; height:300px;"></div>

<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('/dashboard/index.json', function(data){
            //var data = [['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14]];
            plot = jQuery.jqplot('chart10', data, {
                title: ' ',
                //dataRenderer: $.jqplot.ciParser,
                seriesDefaults: {
                    shadow: true,
                    renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        fill: false,
                        sliceMargin: 4,
                        showDataLabels: true
                        }
                },
                legend: { show:true }
            });
        });
    }); // document.ready
</script>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something?  Your json return variable `data` looks like this:

```
{"Bills & Utilities":1019.11,"Uncategorized":196.57,"Home":30.29,"Entertainment":300.0,"Food & Dining":465.45,"Personal Care":63.92,"Auto & Transport":571.44}
```

While jqPlot wants it like this:

```
[["Bills & Utilities",1019.11],["Uncategorized",196.57],["Home",30.29],["Entertainment",300.0],["Food & Dining",465.45],["Personal Care",63.92],["Auto & Transport":571.44]]
```

**Edits For Comment**

Putting the data in the correct format:

```
data = {"Bills & Utilities":1019.11,"Uncategorized":196.57,"Home":30.29,"Entertainment":300.0,"Food & Dining":465.45,"Personal Care":63.92,"Auto & Transport":571.44};

jqData = []
$.each(data, function(k,v){jqData.push([k,v]);});
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5dFYW/).

Comment: Mark, i used "dataRenderer: $.jqplot.ciParser" which i commented out in the above code. Isn't that suppose to format the JSON that was returned by rails app to the one that is supported by jqplot?

Comment: Not sure what ciParser is/does (I'm not a rails user anymore).  Doing the data transform though, is pretty simplistic.  See Edits.